# Moving free space from from one LVM LV to another

Tags: linux, lvm

I've got an SSD partitioned into:

- sdc1: 500MB /boot
- sdc2: volume group

  - 10GB  lv_root
  - 100GB  lv_home
  - 50GB  lv_swap
- free: 70GB

It turns out a 10GB root is a bit on the small side and I'd like to expand it by 50% either by stealing it from the neighboring "lv_home", or by using a bit of the free space.

It looks like I'm allowed to reduce "lv_home" by 5GB, but I'm unsure what I then need to do to make this space available to "lv_home". Do I need to relocate "lv_home" to start 5GB higher, or can I create a new extent for "lv_root"?

I've checked the LVM docs but they seem a bit vague on this.

Comment: **50gb for swap?**  Really?  I know SSDs are relatively fast, but if you ever need to use that much swap your system is still going be so painfully slow.  If that is really 50GB for swap, I would cut that down to 4-8GB and re-allocate that space first...

Comment: Yep, really. Hibernation space.

Answer (score 2):

First, boot into rescue mode or use a live CD, since you can't have your root partition mounted when you want to resize it (not even read-only).

This simplest way would be to add the free space to your existing volume: create a partition in that space (I assume it will be /dev/sdc3), set its type to 8e, 'Linux LVM', then add that volume to your volume group:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdc3
vgextend MY_LVM /dev/sdc3
```

Then resize your root volume:

```
lvresize -L +5G /dev/MY_LVM/root
```

Followed by resizing your filesystem:

```
resize2fs /dev/MY_LVM/root
```

(or whatever tool is apropriate for your filesystem).

Alternatively, move the hibernation/swap space to your 70GB free space, delete the lv_swap volume and add some space to lv_root.

To answer your second question: no, you don't need to move LV volumes. That's the beauty of Logical Volume Management; you can shrink or expand volumes without having to move then, in contrast to fixed partitions. You can spread the LVM across multiple disks and/or partitions (as described above). You could say that an LVM is like a simple filesystem with giant blocks and files. The 'files' are your volumes.

Comment: I don't know what filesystems you are using, but at least ext3/ext4 and XFS support growing the filesystem while mounted (XFS actually _only_ supports growing while mounted). Using rescue mode or Live CD for that is completely pointless.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ext3 doesn't allow resizing while mounted since it's essentially an extension of ext2. But I would still use a live CD when fiddling with my root file system... doing that would be similar to changing the wheel on your car while driving down the highway. Technically possible but not recommended.

Comment: According to the man page "As of this writing, the Linux 2.6 kernel supports on-line resize for filesystems mounted using ext3 and ext4." You can guess that that was written a long time ago by the lack of mention of a specific 2.6 version. You only need to do offline resizing when you want to shrink the filesystem. And that's how I've always done it (by necessity for those filesystems that used XFS). If you are going to reboot into a Live CD for every little adjustment of your volumes, you are wasting much of LVMs power anyway.